# Limit 2 bounds of a vector in IF condition

Tags: r, if-statement, warnings

I want to limit the 2 bounds of a vector in a IF condition. However I get the warnings "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used" when I try to use the following function :

```
rho <- c(0.8,0,-0.5)
sigma.S <- 0.4
sigma.M <- 0.1
mu.S <- 0.06
T <- 1
N <- 365
dt <- T/N

m <- c(100,102,100,99,101)

z <- rnorm(N)
P <- matrix(0, N, 1)
P[1] <- m[1]

for (i in 2:N){
  
  P[i] <- P[i-1]*( 1 + sigma.M*sqrt(dt)*z[i] )
}

tPts <- c(0,91,182,273,364)
yPts <- c(m[1]-P[1],m[2]-P[92],m[3]-P[183],m[4]-P[274],m[5]-P[365])

a <- tPts[1]
A <- yPts[1]

for(i in 2:5){
    
  t <- seq(0,364,1)
  b <- tPts[i]
  B <- yPts[i]
    
  if(a<=t & t<=b){
      
    y <- ( B*(t-a) - A*(t-b) )/(b-a)
      
    return(y)
  }
    
  a <- b
  A <- B
}
```

Can anyone see what the problem is here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try with `ifelse` instead of `if/else` if the length is greater than 1

Comment: Inside the code, the `t` is of `length` greater than 1 `t <- seq(0,364,1)` and `if/else` requires input condition to return single TRUE/FALSE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could change the `if` condition inside the loop by wrapping with `all`

```
if(all(a<=t) & all(t<=b))
```

assuming that we need condition to meet along the length  of 't'

as `a <= t` or `t <= b` returns a logical vector of the same `length` as 't' and here 't' is created as a sequence from 0 to 364 i.e. even if one of the vector is of length 1 i.e. 'a' or 'b', the comparison operator does a recycling of that element to the do comparison across the larger length vector

```
5 < (1:6)
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

and `if/else` requires input to be of length 1.

Comment: I added all() into the loop and it worked. However when I find my result y, it return " Error: object 'y' not found". Do you know why?